# Why doesn't Perl's `$shm->remove` from `IPC::SharedMem` remove the shared memory segment?

Tags: linux, perl, shared-memory, resource-cleanup

I wrote a simple web server that uses `IPC::SharedMem` (`IPC::SharedMem->new(IPC_PRIVATE, $size, S_IRWXU)`) and forks off processes to handle client requests.
When the server exited cleanly (and killed all client processes before), the shared memory isn't removed, although my program end with these lines:

```perl
if (parse_options()) {
#...
    print "$me: removing Shared Memory\n"
        if ($verbose > 1);
    $shm->remove;
    my $ret = $shm->remove;
    print "$me: result of removing Shared Memory: $ret\n"
} else {
    exit(1);
}
```

Actually my process ends with these messages:

```text
...
child_create[20166]: child exits with 0
_child_handler: got 20166, have 20166
_child_handler: child PID 20166 exited with 0
REST-server: no longer accepting connections on http://localhost:37709/:
REST-server: removing Shared Memory
REST-server: result of removing Shared Memory: 0 but true
```

So the last child process 20166 has been waited on, and the call is executed.
Still there is shared memory left over (easily recognizable by user and size):

```text
> ipcs

------ Message Queues --------
key        msqid      owner      perms      used-bytes   messages

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status
0x00000000 16646144   windl      700        4          0
0x00000000 16711681   windl      700        4          0
0x00000000 8880146    root       700        4          0

------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems
```

(The one being owned by `root` is a different version running as `root`).
As can be seen the `nattach` is zero, so it's not used any more, and `ipcrm` has no problem removing those (I wrote a little script to do it when testing my Perl program):

```
> ./clean-shm.sh
+ pcrm -m 16646144 -m 16711681
```

The manual says for the `remove` method:

> Remove the shared memory segment from the system or mark it as removed as long as any processes are still attached to it.

So what's wrong? I'm running on Linux x86_64 (SLES 12, kernel 4.12.14-122.176-default), and the host is in VMware (virtualized).

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful.

Comment: What does `remove` return?  undef?  zero but true?  something else?

Comment: The `ipcs` program ... when is that output printed -- after the server in your program is done (or after the program exits)?  Perhaps at the time when `->remove` is called some processes are still attached, lingering before exiting (cleaning up or some such -- if they made large data structures it can take whole seconds to clean up on exit), so the thing gtes only "_mark it as removed_".  By the time this output comes the processes actually did exit but there was no one to clean up.  Guessing ....

Comment: You can see if you've got any attachments like this: `my $num_attached = $shm->stat->nattch;` Using this before the remove, you'll be able to create delays before the remove() call to see if waiting removes the attachments or not. Note that after a successful remove, you'll get an undef warning. If there are any attachments (nattch) when you call remove(), the remove() call won't do its job properly.

Comment: @Shawn I tried to create a MRE on openSUSE 15.5, but there it worked (using Perl 2.26.1, however). SLES 12 is at 5.18.2, however.

Comment: @zdim Obviously: If I want to verify whether the SHM was removed, it really makes sense to call it after the program has terminated; so I did that ;-)

Comment: @stevieb My program does not attach the SHM; it only uses `read` and `write` methods.

Comment: @pilcrow As the manual page does not state it returns any defined value, I didn't check the result.

Comment: @U.Windl, while the manual page doesn't document it, the [source](https://perldoc.perl.org/IPC::SharedMem.txt) reveals that the first call to `remove` returns the value of [`shmctl`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shmctl) with an IPC_RMID, which would be informative here.

Comment: For some reason hard to explain, the shared memory is removed this week, even when running the same program. So probably I'll delete the question, unless I find the real reason.

Comment: @U.Windl  "_shared memory is removed this week_" -- I may be missing something, but that'd be consistent with a race condition, where those forks just may-or-may-not exit quick enough for `->remove` to be able to do its thing?  (My guess from my earlier comment.)

Comment: @zdim Even if IPC_PRIVATE is a misnomer, shouldn't the SHM be removed when the key is zero and `nattch` is zero, too (and the last process using it has exited)? However I've updated glibc and the Linux kernel since then. Maybe there was a kernel flaw...

Comment: @U.Windl  "_...and the last process using it has exited..._" --   That's precisely it, I am saying that perhaps _not_ all processes have exited when `remove` is called?  Some may be busy cleaning up.  (I don't see the whole picture -- i'm thinking of a bunch of `fork`-ed processes out there, and the parent cleaning up when those forks are expected to be out -- but they actually aren't.  Perhaps that's an incorrect picture... If that's so I apologize for guessing and please disregard :)